# add button inside custom column in sales order grid page

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I added new column in **Sales Order Grid** & successfully added **title** [say **download**] of column, now i want to add button [ say button name `download1`] for all rows of that column.

I did't created any column in database as i dont want to fetch anyy value from database.

[image]

app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php :
**Function** : **_prepareColumns()**

```
$this->addColumn('download',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('download'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'download1',  
                'type' => 'text'         
            ));
```

Comment: Try with render method it will work

Comment: @Magento2 it worked , thanks..... you can post it as an answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with render method

```
**''renderer'  => 'module/adminhtml_sales_order_render_delete',',**
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend [Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203025/add-button-inside-custom-column-in-sales-order-grid-page/203030#203030) answer , i added as below :

app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php : **Function** : _**prepareColumns()**

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '100px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'renderer'  => 'deleteorder/adminhtml_sales_order_render_delete',
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
```

app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Render - **Delete.php** :

```
class Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Render_Delete extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $getData = $row->getData();
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to delete this order?');
        $orderID = $getData['entity_id'];
        $view = $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view',array('order_id' => $orderID));
        $delete = $this->getUrl('*/deleteorder/delete',array('order_id' => $orderID));
        $link = '<a href="'.$download.'">Download</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a>';
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do this in magento 2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270045/how-to-add-custom-column-as-link-in-sales-order-grid-in-magento-2