# How to add custom column as link in sales order grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6, order-grid, link, custom-column-grid

I wish to add a column as link in sales order grid. While clicking the link, I wish to perform some logic,

I have reffered the below link for magento 1 which is based on layout grid
[add button inside custom column in sales order grid page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203025/add-button-inside-custom-column-in-sales-order-grid-page)

I need the same solution for magento 2

Many blogs are available to add custom column in sales order grid, but no luck

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Thanks for your response,Let you know once i get

Answer (score 2):

I have created one column as "sku" in a custom grid. It displays SKU as a link and also its redirect into view page.

**In XML:**

```
<column name="sku" class="XXX\Movements\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sku</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

**In Product.php:**

```
<?php

namespace XXX\Movements\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory as ProductCollection;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Product extends Column
{

    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_product;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, ProductCollection $product, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    $productId = $this->_product->create()->getIdBySku($item[$fieldName]);
                    $html = "<a  href='" . $this->context->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => $productId]) . "'>";
                    $html .= $item[$fieldName];
                    $html .= "</a>";
                    $item[$fieldName] = $html;
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```

It may be helpful for your scenario.

Comment: if you can add some info (explanation) in your answer it would be better. Please clarify as well in which **xml** file should the code above be added.